# Iterative calculations using result from previous calculation - R

Tags: r, iteration, calculation

I posted this question a while ago, with a lot of great suggestions, but none of them finalize to the same result that I achieved using Excel.

Lets say we have the following parameters:

```
Pd.sil.initial = 0.011
Pd.sul.i = 30
Pd.sul.f = ?
R.inc = 100
D.Pd = 536000
```

I need to calculate Pd.sul.f using the equation:

Pd.sul.f = (Pd.sul.i + (R.inc * Pd.sil.i)) / (1 + (R.inc / D.Pd))

This needs to be done iteratively with the Pd.sul.f result of the previous calculation being used as the Pd.sul.i of the next calculation. I provided a screenshot of my Excel worksheet highlighting this, along with the answers to the first few calculations.

[image: Excel calculation]

The R code that was suggested to me before, but is unfortunately not providing the same results as my Excel worksheet is:

```
Pd.sul.f <- function(n) {

 return(Pd.sul.i + n * (R.inc * Pd.sil.i) / (1 + R.inc/D.Pd))

}

sapply(1:100000, Pd.sul.f)
```

Any help to figure out how I could accomplish this would be greatly appreciated. I am relatively new to R, so a simpler answer would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you please share some sample reproducible data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
Pd.sil.initial = 0.011
Pd.sul.i = 30
R.inc = 100
D.Pd = 536000

n=10

a <- data.frame(matrix(,nrow=n, ncol=1))

for (i in 1:n) {
   Pd.sul.f <- ((Pd.sul.i + (R.inc * Pd.sil.initial)) / (1 + R.inc / D.Pd))
   a[i,] <- Pd.sul.f
   Pd.sul.i <- Pd.sul.f
}
```

Where n is the number of iterations.

EDIT to answers Matt second question :

```
Pd.sil.initial = 0.011
Pd.sul.i = 30
R.inc = 100
D.Pd = 536000

n=10

a <- data.frame(matrix(,nrow=n, ncol=2))
a[1,1] <- 30
a[1,2] <- 100

for (i in 2:n) {
   Pd.sul.f <- ((Pd.sul.i + (R.inc * Pd.sil.initial)) / (1 + R.inc / D.Pd))
   a[i,1] <- Pd.sul.f
   a[i,2] <- i * 100
   Pd.sul.i <- Pd.sul.f
}
```

Or simply:

```
for (i in 2:n) {
  a[i,1] <- ((a[[1]][[i-1]] + (R.inc * Pd.sil.initial)) / (1 + R.inc / D.Pd))
  a[i,2] <- a[[2]][[i-1]] + 100
}
```

Comment: If I could ask one more thing, how would I go about creating a database that sums the R.inc to generate the cumulative R at each iteration - this is the Rcum column in the screenshot posted above? I tried following the code you wrote, but the result doesn't start at 100.

Comment: I edited my post to answers your question :).

Comment: Ah this is fantastic, thank you again for your help. Looking forward to the day I can work through problems like this. Cheers.